# Active directory: Tracking the origin of a specific permission

Tags: active-directory, permissions

How can I track why a specific user has that particular permission? Use case scenario:

Under effective permissions, I'm selecting a user. I can see that this particular user has a write user account control permission. I'd like to know, why this user has that permission. Is it from group membership and if yes, from which group? Or maybe it has been delegated?

When I see permissions on a user object there are a lot of groups and it is not possible to see, which group membership gives you specific permission.